# Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type '() => Observable<any>'

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable, angular2-services

service file

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { Http,Response} from '@angular/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/Map';

@Injectable()
export class VideoService {

   private geturl = '/api/videos';
   constructor(private _http:Http) { }

   getvideos() {
       return this._http.get(this.geturl).map((response:Response) => {
          response.json()
       });
   }
}
```

here is where the subscribe method showing this error

```
import { VideoService } from '../video.service';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Video } from '../video';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';


@Component({
    selector: 'app-videocenter',
    templateUrl: './videocenter.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./videocenter.component.css']
})
export class VideocenterComponent implements OnInit {
    videos: any;
    onselectvideo: Video;
    switch: boolean = false

    constructor(private videoserv: VideoService) {
        //console.log(this.videos);
    }
    onselect(vid: any) {
        this.switch = true;
        this.onselectvideo = vid;
        console.log(vid);
    }
    ngOnInit() {
         this.videos = this.videoserv.getvideos .subscribe((response) => {
             this.videos = response;
         });
    }

}
```

i have service file in which i have to call my api to get the api's and when i am going to subscribe the method in the other class where i am calling that service method getvideos() then its showing the error that the property "subscribe " does not exist on type ()=> observable

Comment: Also, `switch` is a protected word. You won't be able to use it as a variable name.

Comment: I am getting Property 'map' does not exist on type 'string'. at this: return this._http.get(this.geturl).map((response:Response) => {
          response.json()
       });

Answer (score 118, accepted):

You are not calling the `getVideos` method. You are calling `subscribe` on the function reference of `getVideos` and not the returned value. Call `subscribe` after you call `getVideos()`:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.videoserv.getvideos().subscribe((response) => {
         this.videos = response
    });
}
```

Comment: I had the exact same problem and could not figure out why it was not working. Thanks man!

Answer (score 6):

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.videoserv.getvideos().subscribe((response) => {
         this.videos = response
    });
}
```

You should be calling the `getvideos()` method on the `videoserv` service.
You were missing the `()`, `getvideos` is a method not a property.

Answer (score 3):

```
this.service.method().subscribe(response)...
```

Whenever `this.service` is typed and auto suggestion appears, in suggestion , method name is suggested and once suggestion is accepted, it takes up only method name without parenthesis().

`this.service.method.subscribe()..` => Will give error

`this.service.method().subscibe()..` => Correct

Answer (score 1):

But if you also want to use your service method *getvideos()* in another place of your application (component, pipe...etc)

You can do *.pipe(map())* instead of *.subscribe()*

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.videoserv.getvideos().pipe(map(response) => {
         this.videos = response
    }));
}
```

And then use *.subscribe* in the place where you want to have your videos

```
   this.videoserv.getvideos().subscribe(response) => {
         this.videos2 = response
    });
```