# Define service property and access it in component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angularfire2

Not sure how to access the `admin` property from `AuthService`. The same exact code in the component sets `this.admin` to the value from the database, but I don't want to rewrite the code in every component.

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthService {

public admin: any;

constructor() {
    this.currentUser.take(1).subscribe(user => {
          if (user) {
            this.db.object(`/users/${user.uid}`).subscribe(usr => this.setAdmin(usr));
          }
        });
    }
}


setAdmin(usr) {
    console.log(usr.admin); // returns value from database
    this.admin = usr.admin;
    console.log(this.admin); // returns usr.admin value
}
```

component

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    public isA: any;


  constructor(public authService: AuthService,){

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.isA = this.authService.admin; // this is undefined
  }
}
```

Component edit *****

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.msgService.getPermission();
    this.msgService.receiveMessage();
    this.message = this.msgService.currentMessage;
      this.authService.currentUser.take(1).subscribe(user => {
        if (user) {
          console.log(user.uid);
          this.db.object(`/users/${user.uid}`).subscribe(usr => this.setAdmin(usr))
        }
      });
  }

  setAdmin(usr) {
    this.admin = usr.admin;
  }
```

Comment: Shouldn't your export block be wrapping your constructor() and ngOnInit() functions in your component?

Comment: it's undefined because the `this.db.object(`/users/${user.uid}`)` is async and hasn't evaluted yet when you access `this.authService.admin` in ngOnInit. You need to return a promise or an observable

Comment: @joshrathke it does ... i just wrote it wrong.

Comment: @AngularInDepth.com so can you explain why it works if I add it to the component?

Comment: @Ciprian, what do you mean if you add it to the component?

Comment: @AngularInDepth.com See my edit ... it sets `this.admin` to `usr.admin`.

Comment: I just figured something out ... I needed to check if the current user is admin to hide or show parts of the template. If I use `<md-list-item *ngIf="authService.admin">` it works ... I just don't know how to access it in  `component.ts`. So half of my problem is solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need a `get` method on your service ideally. Secondly, it's tricky to access a value without knowing when it's gonna be there (ASYNC, doesn't return straight away nor the code stops for it. Like PHP ). 
So your options are to wrap the what you wanna do with the value in the `.subscribe ()` method or have `ngDoCheck (){}` constantly monitor for changes and that will pickup when the value is present (I wouldn't recommend this approach as it runs an any change). Or I prefer to make things as `BehaviourSubject` so that it acts as Observable and you can `Subscribe` to it, that way when ever value changes the component will pick it up automatically.

```js
@Injectable()
export class AuthService {

  public admin: BehaviourSubject < any > = new BehaviourSubject(null);

  constructor() {
    this.currentUser.take(1).subscribe(user => {
      if (user) {
        this.db.object(`/users/${user.uid}`).subscribe(usr => this.setAdmin(usr));
      }
    });
  }
}


setAdmin(usr) {
  console.log(usr.admin); // returns value from database
  this.admin.next (usr.admin);
  console.log(this.admin); // returns usr.admin value
}

getAdmin(): Observable < any > {
  return this.admin.asObservable();
}
```

```js
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  public isA: any;


  constructor(public authService: AuthService, ) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.authService.getAdmin.subscribe((admin: any) => {
      //Anything in here get executed every time the `admin` variable's value chnages
    });
  }

  // If you want to see how the ngDocheck() behave
  ngDoCheck() {
    console.log("DoCheck");
  }
}
```

Comment: I have added a sample and also added `ngDoCheck()` if you want to see how it behaves

Comment: So you're returning `this.admin` as an Observable and then subscribing to it in the component? And I can define any property in the `this.authService.getAdmin.subscribe((admin: any) => {` block ... like `this.myProperty = admin` and then use it in the component.ts as well as component.html ?

Comment: Yes, just like if it is coming from the server. That way the `subscribe` runs automatically when the `BehaviourSubject` changes.

Comment: Ok! Thank you very much! I'll try it out.

Comment: There is still a problem: `Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type '() => Observable<any>'.`

Comment: That might have been the `setAdmin` method. I've updated it now. If the error didn't change, so you know where it's throwing that?

Comment: This explained the problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44092034/property-subscribe-does-not-exist-on-type-observableany ... it should be `this.authService.getAdmin().subscribe((admin: any) => {` in the component. `getAdmin()` missing `()`