# Trying to pass the data between the component using the service

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular7

I am using service to pass the data between the component and my component looks like below

```
  constructor(private psService: ProjectShipmentService, private pdComp: ProjectDetailsComponent) {

  }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.psService.getTDate().subscribe(x => this.cachedResults = x);
    this.populateArrays();
```

where my service is like

```
 constructor(private service: DataService, private pInfo: ProjectDetailsComponent) {

    this.rProjectNumber = this.pInfo.rProjectNumber;
    this.rProjectSO = this.pInfo.rSalesOrder;
    this.entityUrl = this.pInfo.entityUrl;
    this.tDate = service.get<ShipDateFilterModel[]>(this.entityUrl);
   }
```

Eventhough the tDate has data when subscribing it in the Component has no data. this.cachedResults is empty when the service is called on the ngOnInIt lifecycle hook. What am I missing here?

Comment: May be because its has data even before you subscribe it and that is not emitted.. after you subscription.

Comment: @Manish How do I emit it.

Comment: See my answer below thats what will solve you problem..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you simple create a method in service like

```
getTDate(){
return this.service.get<ShipDateFilterModel[]>(this.entityUrl);
}
```

And subscribe in your component

```
this.psService.getTDate().subscribe(x => this.cachedResults = x);
```

Comment: I get the error like Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type '() => Observable<ShipDateFilterModel[]>'.ts(2339) attached the screenshot

Comment: @trx can you show `service.get` function code in your question

Comment: @trx can you check you code looks like `this.psService.getTDate(),subscribe` or `this.psService.getTDate.subscribe`  it should be `this.psService.getTDate(),subscribe` as per my ans may be you are doing the same mistake as specified in this SO https://stackoverflow.com/q/44092034/5621827

Comment: The error was resolved but still I dont see any data in `this.cachedResults`

Comment: @trx can you put console.log in subscribe method like `subscribe(x => {console.log(x)})` and see if this is triggered and something logged to console

Comment: I added the screenshot of my debug window

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200044/discussion-between-jitender-and-trx).

Answer (score 1):

Try it this way..

```
export class ProjectShipmentService {
  rProjectNumber;
  tDate: Observable<ShipDateFilterModel[]>;
  entityUrl;
  rProjectSO;

  constructor(private service: DataService, private pInfo: ProjectDetailsComponent) {
    this.rProjectNumber = this.pInfo.rProjectNumber;
    this.rProjectSO = this.pInfo.rSalesOrder;
    this.entityUrl = this.pInfo.entityUrl;
   }

getTDate(){
    return this.service.get<ShipDateFilterModel[]>(this.entityUrl);
}
```

And in your component.

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.psService.getTDate.subscribe(x => this.cachedResults = x);
    this.populateArrays();
  }
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I get the error like `Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type '() => Observable<ShipDateFilterModel[]>'.ts(2339)` attached the screenshot

Comment: your method `service.get` what does it returns?

Comment: Response from the API

Comment: can you share the code for that method. it should return a observable.

Comment: Check this out i have created demo with a public api and it works fine now you can compare and see whats the difference and may be correct it. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kttgph